# How to change content of a JTextArea after user prompt

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

This is my first question on stackoverflow. So hopefully you are not as that strict to me :).

Well, I read many posts about the JTextArea problem but I could not get the solution there. I read things about swing workers, propertychangelisteners and other stuff. I am still quite unsure in these parts of programming. I use NETBEANS 8.0.

My program is about translating after the prompt of a user from one language in another. And if a String variable for the JTextArea is filled with content the JTextArea itself should update its text.

I have implemented a Getter Method to get the translated string.

Thus the initialization of the GUI Frame with a JTextArea:

```
public class MF extends javax.swing.JFrame implements int_mainframe {
   protected static String str_output = null;
   private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea; 

   @Override
   public void setStrOutput(String string) {
      str_output = string;
      jTextArea.setText(str_output);
   }

   public MF() {
      initComponents();
   }

   private void initComponents() {
      jTextArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
   }                            

   java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
         new MF().setVisible(true);
      }
   });
}
```

The String Variable for this class is filled with content in class stacystart main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MF mf = new MF();       
    mf.setStrOutput(str_output);
}
```

I am getting frustrated to that even though the function is so simple. Need help please!

Comment: Any particular reason you allocate a new string in `SetStrOutput`?

Comment: @Vince Emigh: I want to update, refresh, whatever my JTextArea with a new string after getting invoked by this class.

Comment: @Chief Two Pencils: Not really. Actually it is a private static class string variable. I thought maybe it is more evident to show this like this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you ever invoke the `SetStrOuput(...)` method?
2. Follow Java naming conventions. Method names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Comment: Yes SetStrOuput() [I changed it now to set_str_output] is invoked and the translated string is handed over to this class. I can see this in the debugger system. Thank you for the naming convention!

Comment: Well, it is not invoked in the code you posted so you need to post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and then maybe someone will be able to help.

Comment: @Vitt3x: you didn't actually do much better with the new name. camickr is probably referring to [Naming a Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) according to the Java tutorial.

Comment: @Vitt3x, Why are you using "_" in your method names. Show me one method name in the JDK that does this. Don't make up your own conventions. Learn by example. Also, the code you posted in not a SSCCE so I can't help.

Comment: Okay got this with the underscore... I will apply that. The SSCCE I still have to study first. After further research I think I have to use a SwingWorker for updating the text of jTextArea. But it is still work to apply this in my case...

Comment: No you don't need a SwingWorker, when you click a button the code will execute on the Event DispatchThread. All you need is a simple ActionListener which translates the text in the text area and invokes the setText(...) method on the other text area with the translated text. Again the SSCCE should just be a simple frame with two text areas and a button. Start by just taking the text from the first text area and copy it to the second text area. Once you have that simple step working then you add the translation. Do one step at a time.

Comment: I already had a button and an actionlistener. But this is quite uncomfortable for the user. I want to display the result just right after it is avaible through the setter method.